# How can i get the highest score from laravel query

Tags: laravel

My table as below

[image]

How i want to show data from

name   score

Riyal  17

demo2  11

demo3  9

demo1  1

I want to show from higest to low and will show only 10 data from table.

my code is

```
 public function index()
{
    $score_board = ScoreBoard::orderBy('id')->max('score');
    return new ScoreBoardResource($score_board);
}
```

but it gives me nothing. Any idea how can i do it

Answer (score 2):

`->max('score')` would return `17`... If you want 10 records, sorted highest to lowest, you need to use the proper methods:

```php
$scoreBoard = ScoreBoard::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
```

Please read the Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset